# Novel, Lo Tech SF/Fantasy, Powerful Woman, Male Assistant, Quest, Trilogy

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

Looking for the name of a SF or fantasy novel.

I probably read this in the 70's or 80's.  Believe was first published post 1960.  *Could* be part of a larger series.  My faulty memory keeps trying to tell me the author was a woman - but really not sure...

Basic plot that I can remember:  Two main characters (probably human, or close) involved in some type of quest (which takes place on a planetary surface, most likely utilizing some type of non-advanced, animal-type transportation - horses perhaps).  One character is a woman who has nobility in her background.  The other character is her faithful assistant, a male.

Somehow, I want to say that a major sub-plot involves the woman's gradual realization of the inherent worth and "nobility" of her assistant.  I want to say that the two were never lovers, but I'm not sure...

The novel was quite good, rather long (as I recall), and had quite an impact on me during my younger years.

Comment: This seems a bit vague.  The obvious answer is the Morgaine saga (starting with [The Gate of Ivrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_of_Ivrel)) by C.J. Cherryh, but there could be many more.

Comment: @DavidW, you nailed it!  Please submit an answer along these lines.  I devoured the first three books in this series about 40 years ago!  Still sticks with me...

Comment: Then you still have Exiles Gate to read!

Comment: Addressing the observations wrt "duplicate question":  I agree that the associated link _does_ ask the same question as I did.  However, said link did not appear in any of my several search attempts.  By leaving my current question as is, perhaps a future searcher would have better luck than did I...just a thought.  I _will_, however, in good faith, tinker with the title a bit...

Comment: Digger, please note that your question being marked as a duplicate does not mean that either it or your asking of it is a problem. Duplicate questions are linked (see top of sidebar at right) to allow sharing of summary information, because, as you note, this can help future searchers. Welcome to the stack!

Comment: At Otis says, being marked duplicate doesn't mean your question is less valid.  If I were to search here for a book that had a villain who couldn't be permanently killed, because his consciousness would be imprinted on the next person to use a gate, that wouldn't match _any_ of the 3 existing questions whose answer is "Gate of Ivrel."  Duplicate questions are fine, because it's impossible to know what people will recall of a story, or what they'll search for.  Marking duplicates is more about trying to organize things to point to the best possible answers.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks guys!  On a side note, what is it about the "stackexchange" family of sites that engenders such civic behavior (for the most part) from its contributors?  Seems to be only a minimal amount of flaming going on around here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the description, the story that leaps to mind is [Gate of Ivrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gate_of_Ivrel) and the following books of the [Morgaine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?264) saga by C.J. Cherryh.

C.J. Cherryh is a female author, check.

Morgaine is a powerful (not technically aristocratic, but competent, sophisticated and old beyond her apparent years, so able to fake it) woman on a quest to destroy the gate of the title and all others like it.

Nhi Vanye i Chya is a young sub-noble (merely a dai-uyo as I believe he puts it) warrior who is outcast from his family and joins Morgaine on her quest.

Initially Morgaine merely tolerates Nhi Vanye as a local guide, intending to abandon him when she closes the gate.  But they are pursued through the gate, cutting him off from his homeland with no way to return, so she keeps him.  Eventually (in later books) she trusts and values him enough to entrust her quest to him in the event she should fall.

[image: Gate of Ivrel cover]

Comment: I was thinking of those books, too. A trilogy in the late 1970s, and then a fourth one in the late 80s where Cherryh finally gave in and let the two of them start having a love affair. (Previously, it had been made pretty darn clear that this wasn't going to happen, and I felt it was a mistake on her part to reverse herself.)

Comment: @Lorendiac ymmv! I thought it showed that Morgaine now considered Vanye an equal (or at least a partner not an underling) and that Vanye saw himself as a partner. I have a print of the Exile's Gate cover.

Comment: @mkennedy I kinda agree with Lorendiac.  Even if Morgaine has come to accept Vanye as a partner, it's still a bit of a betrayal of her absolute commitment to her quest.

Comment: @Lorendiac: My impression was that the third novel, Fires of Azeroth, already made it very clear they had developed mutual romantic feelings. The main thing left was for Morgaine to admit to herself that absolute commitment doesn't make her invulnerable and a partner could ultimately be someone who continues the quest if she dies - and that being an emotionless questing machine might not be sustainable.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt It has been many years since I last looked through my copy of *Fires of Azeroth,* but I *think* I remember a bit wherein Vanye thinks, without saying anything about it in dialogue, that he's already gotten the silent message that Moiraine doesn't want any romantic complications to *mess up* the good working relationship they have developed as they carry out her quest to keep closing those gates on world after world. But it's been so long that I can't remember the exact wording, nor the details of any other passages in that book which hinted at mutual attraction.

Comment: @Lorendiac: I just reread the passage I had in mind, about 10 pages from the end. Morgaine offers to braid Vanye's hair, which is reserved to close family and lovers in his customs. He accepts after *explicitly* confirming that she's aware of that. Shortly afterwards, she spare's Roh's life against her instincts, for Vanye's sake. It think that Morgaine's initial cold aloofness was never meant to be her true character as much as her way of dealing with losing all her remaining friends to treason, which happened only a few months before the beginning of the series, in her own timeline.